How to prevent terminal windows from resizing after disconnecting external monitor?
My Terminal windows are 80x24. I usually use my MacBook in clamshell mode connected to my studio display. When I disconnect my Mac to work on the built-in display the windows get resized to 84x24. So I resize them to 80x24. But when I connect to my monitor again, they get resized to 76x24.
Is there any way to completely disable resizing of Terminal windows when disconnecting/reconnecting?
Open to using a third-party app but I'm partial to Terminal. It's much lighter weight than the other terminal apps I've used (e.g. iTerm2).
